# Openvpn and openconnect are not working on Manjaro

Tags: openvpn, manjaro, openconnect

I'm using Manjaro. I recently Installed OpenVPN and openconnect and both of them are installed with the latest version. When I try to use one ( Usually openconnect ) I use this command:

```
sudo openconnect server-address
```

And then I use my username and password. It says :

```
Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS1.2)-(PSK)-(AES-256-GCM).
```

Which I assume that means it is connected successfuly. but then it gives this to me :

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
```

I have updated my os ( It is Manjaro 18 ) and I've tried restarting systemd.service but It didn't solve my problem. What should I do?

I Also have tried This one :

```
systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service `
```

But after that , after vpn connecting to the server it gives the previous error without the last 2 lines :

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```